# Debugging on my phone (Eclipse, Android)

Tags: android, debugging

I want to run and debug my Android apps on my HTC Incredible.    On http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html it says I have to install the Windows USB driver.  And the instructions for that says:

*"1.    Connect your Android-powered device to your computer's USB port. Windows will detect the device and launch the Hardware Update Wizard"*

But it **doesn't**.   When I connect my phone it's visible as a drive letter and its SD card is visible as a second drive letter and I can transfer files.   But Hardware Update Wizard doesn't launch.   Nor is it already connected -  if I go to my SDK tools directory and do "adb devices" it returns blank.

So what do I have to do to debug on my phone?     Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Android Simplicity](http://android-simplicity.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-1-how-to-install-usb-driver-on.html) has some tips for troubleshooting the installation of the Windows USB driver. If that doesn't help, try following the steps laid out [here](http://www.flexjunk.com/2010/05/01/installing-htc-incredible-android-sd-drivers/) (which are specific to htc incredible).

Finally, according to [this forum](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-incredible-tech-issues/52644-help-need-adb-driver-windows-xp.html), it seems that it may be necessary to install [HTC Sync](https://support.htc.com/alerts_downloads/en/HTC_Sync_and_Sync_Manager_for_all_HTC_Android_Phones) in order to get debugging to work in Eclipse.

Comment: I apologize for not making it clear that I'm using XP, SP3  - the FlexJunk page is for Windows 7.   The Android Simplicity one implies at the beginning that I need to install the drivers to transfer files to/from the phone.  But I can do that now.  However the phone doesn't show up as an adb device, which is why I don't think they're installed.

Comment: See my update. It looks like HTC Sync might be the missing piece of the puzzle.

Comment: I SPOKE TOO SOON!  The FlexJunk page started off talking about Win7, but it also has a hack for the android_winusb.inf file for XP and that hack fixes the problem!

Comment: What happened to the post that suggested the FlexJunk link?   I want to mark it as the answer but it's gone!

Answer (score 3):

Did you put your device into debug mode?  This should be found under Settings-> Applications->Development.

Comment: Yes, USB debugging is checked, and so is Stay awake.

Answer (score 2):

Ryan's answer helped me with this problem, too. For archival purposes, here's what I did:

Install the USB Driver using Android SDK Manager:

[image: Install the USB Driver using Android SDK Manager]

Find and edit `android_winusb.inf` following the instructions from http://www.flexjunk.com/2010/05/01/installing-htc-incredible-android-sd-drivers/. Mine was located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`

---

> Find the section labeled [Google.NTx86]. At the end of that section,
>   add the following lines.

```
;
;HTC Incredible
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C9E
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C9E&MI_01
```

> Find the section [Google.NTamd64]. At the end of that section, add the
>   following lines.

```
;
;HTC Incredible
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C9E
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C9E&MI_01
```

> On your Incredible, go to Settings->Applications->Development and turn
>   on USB debugging. NOW, you can connect your phone to the PC.
>
> On your PC, Go to Start->Right-Click My Computer->Manage
>
> You should see a device with a warning on it called Other->ADB.
>   Right-click it and choose Update Driver Software… Install the drivers
>   manually and point that to your usb_drivers folder. Ignore any
>   warnings about unsigned drivers and everything should install just
>   fine. After installation, I see Android Phone->Android Composite ADB
>   Interface in the Device Manager.

Comment: If you're using Windows 7 or Vista you may have to use the following Device Manager options if the INF file is not found when you choose the `usb_drivers` folder. Go to, Install Manually, then List Drivers, choose All Devices, then click Have Disk, choose the INF file.