# Problem with installing an application on android

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I modified my manifest.xml to debuggable, connected the android to the pc, went to settings application and changed it to allow external applications to be installed and allow debugging..

When I press on debug button in eclipse. It gives me a choice to choose between debugging with the device or debug with AVD..

the problem is that the device (Android Nexus One) doesnt appear, even though the pc hardware does identify it..(I can access its folders).

1) How do i get an apk file..
2) and how do i install it into the android phone..or put it into the phone

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.SpendingCutter"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

changed it and still doesnt recognize the device

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to turn on USB debugging on the phone. On my HTC Incredible its under Menu->Settings->Applications->Debugging

Comment: Can you run the application in the simulator (AVD) running your phone's version of the Android API properly? I'm assuming you can, but just double checking.

Answer (score -1):

You won't get an `.apk` file, eclipse will automatically install it on the device.

Everything seems ok, `USB debugging` is enabled & you can access files. Then maybe your project target version is incompatible with the Android version on the device.

What happens is that you are building your project for a version that is newer than the android version on your device. So you need to change your target to an older version.

In your manifest file lower the value in the following line to something that matches your device:

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />`

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html

Comment: My version is 2.3.4 ..above when i click the debug it tells me insert a device compatible with target android 3.0.. what do i do..it doesnt appear

Comment: changed it to 10..wont change anything

Comment: i think the problem is that it is an htc phone and need some special application to have it installed to work with windows... 6 doesnt work

Comment: Did you try installing `HTC Sync`? Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038613/debugging-on-my-phone-eclipse-android