# Android AVD - Faster On Windows Or On Ubuntu VM?

Tags: android, ubuntu, virtual-machine, android-virtual-device

My Android emulator runs painfully slow on my PC so I was thinking about installing Ubuntu on a virtual machine and running the AVD there. Do you think it would be faster if I did so?

Comment: The Android emulator is just slow in general. It's better to develop on a real device if you can. There isn't any reason to expect it to be faster inside a VM.

Comment: Is there a way to connect a *real* Android device up to my PC (let's say using a USB connection) and run/test all my apps there? Or do would I have to create the APK and install it each time?

Comment: Yes. Typically you just enable development in the `Settings` app on the device and then just run your apps in the same way as you would on the emulator.

Comment: My development environment is Eclipse ADT. Right now the way I run my apps is just start the AVD then in Eclipse I select "Run as Android Application." If I connected a hardware device to my USB port the ADT would recognize it and behave the same way?

Comment: Yes, in the Eclipse run configuration settings, you can tell it to prefer a USB device. Then when you press the run button, it'll install/run the app on the device instead of emulator. AVD doesn't need to be running.

Answer (score 1):

you have two solution.

one, you install AndroVM on VirtualBox.

[AndroVM](http://androvm.org/)

this way is very faster, but bit difficult to setup and controll.

other way is create AVD which is made in Intel x86.

[Configuring the x86 Emulator](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/configuring_the_x86_emulator)

this way is very fast too.and setup and controll is very easy compare to general emulator.

but this way require CPU which support Intel VT / AMD-V

both way is good,please choose you like :)

Answer (score 0):

I would put my money on Linux - as it has less of a footprint OS wise.

On the other hand, Windows is by far more used, so if they've developed it and put time into the one that is used the most, it could be Windows.

As a side note: there are several new android emulators that run on windows, some I've seen actually interface with the hardware (this avoids a layer of abstraction).

If your concerned with speed, you will get better performance with less programs running as the emulator is process intensive. (My i7, 8gb ram, is usable for developing - though nothing beats a device... Or nexus for that matter)

To connect to your computer: [Debugging on my phone (Eclipse, Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038613/debugging-on-my-phone-eclipse-android)