# Not connected HTC Desire C with eclipse

Tags: android

I continuously receive this error on window 8.

```
No active compatible AVD's or devices found. Relaunch this configuration after connecting a device or starting an AVD.
```

I add

```
android:debuggable="true"
```

in manifestfile and also restart the adb but did not work.

I try to install google driver from < sdk> extras\google\usb_driver via window Manager but it not detect these drivers.

I also add line in android_winusb.inf from this thread.
[Debugging on my phone (Eclipse, Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038613/debugging-on-my-phone-eclipse-android)

These lines in Ronnie Overby answer.

Please tell me how to fix this.

Comment: you should install the driver first

Comment: I receive this message 
window could not find driver software for your device.

Comment: search google for the driver(driver for your phone, not google usb driver), install it, enable debugging USB on your phone, check it agan

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing the sync manager, the drivers come along with it:
http://www.htc.com/www/software/htc-sync-manager/

Comment: bit of an overkill (200 mb~), but worked for my colleague (I don't use windows myself)

Comment: Where to give this 200mb. Uku Loskit