# Samsung S3 not detected anymore after update to Android Version 4.3

Tags: android, offline, drivers

I recently updated my Samsung S3 to Android 4.3
Earlier everything was working smooth but now my device is not getting listed in adb shell.
It is getting connected but always shown "offline".

I tried all the solutions I found online :

- Changed USB port.
- Changed USB Cable.
- Pulled-out and restarted my device.
- Restarted System / Eclipse.
- Factory Reset of phone.
- Re-installed drivers.

Please HELP.

Comment: Try updating ur IDE .

Comment: You should try updating add, also make sure that the debugging is enabled, and try again.

Comment: yes it is enabled. Going for the update now..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debugging on my phone (Eclipse, Android)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038613/debugging-on-my-phone-eclipse-android)

Comment: Not a programming question. Ask at xda / superuser / android-enthusiasts.

Comment: I guess it is a part of the same phase .. Anyways I got it resolved :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try any one of these:

1. Enable the developer option in S3. I think it might be disabled after the update.
2. install Samsung android driver into your laptop.

[Please add any settings if I have missed]

Comment: I have enabled the developer option already

Comment: Then you need to wait for others to answer. Cheers.

Comment: I had to update my adb version. it was somehow getting reverted even after updating it. I finally downloaded it separately and replaced the folder then restarted my eclipse. Finally it worked !!!!!